# Hunting Birds probability

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

A hunter locates 20 geese, 25 ducks 40 eagles, 10 ostriches, and 5 flamingos. He randomly selects 6 birds to target. What is the probability at least one of each species is targeted?

My reasoning $20 \choose 1$ $25 \choose 1$ $40 \choose 1$ $10 \choose 1$ $5 \choose 1$ $5\choose 1$ for the numerator because there are 5 ways to choose 1 species that will be targeted twice. For the denominator  its $100 \choose 6$. However book says im wrong what did i forget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you forgot two things. You don't just have to choose which species is targeted twice, you have to choose which bird to target. Up to this point you've been counting individual birds, not species. So that last factor of $\binom51$ should be corrected to $\binom{95}1$. But now you have **over** counted by a factor of $2$, because the two birds of the same kind could have been chosen in either order.

Edited to answer follow-up questions.

Overcounting is not necessarily something to be avoided. Sometimes the best way to solve a counting problem is to overcount by a definite known factor (a factor of $2$ in your question) and then correct by dividing out the overcount factor.

For example, the number of $5$-card **combinations** from a $52$ card deck is, as you know given by the formula $\binom{52}5=\dfrac{52\cdot51\cdot50\cdot49\cdot48}{5!}$. Do you remember how that formula was derived? It was derived by first counting the number of $5$-card **permutations**, which is $52\cdot51\cdot50\cdot49\cdot48$, observing that we have overcounted the **combinations** by a factor of $5!$ (since there are $5!$ permutations for each combination, and so we divide the number of permutations by $5!$ to get the number of combinations.

In your problem, you're targeting two birds of the same kind, say two ducks. One duck was chosen first, and appears in the $\binom{25}1$ factor. The other duck was chosen second, and appears in the final $\binom51$ factor. Those two ducks could just as well have been chosen in the other order, so you're double counting.

When it's too hard to see what's going on by abstract thinking, here's a trick you can use: scale down the problem; create an analogous problem with the smallest numbers that make sense. E.g., $4$ ducks, $3$ geese; a hunter shoots $3$ of the $7$ birds; what's the probability that he gets at least one of each kind? The numbers are small enough so you can get the answer ($30/35$) by brute force. You can take the method you used on the big problem and apply it to the miniature problem, and you will know if you get the right answer or not. If your method produces the wrong answer on the miniature problem, you may be able to **see** why it's wrong.

Comment: How am I suppose to know when I overcount? Was there another way to interpret this problem so that I can avoid this overcounting issue?

Comment: Yes I understand now. The little example you came up with is not solvable unless you divide by 2. So how do you know what number to divide by? Will it always be by 2? What would be a example if it was 4 or 5 or 3?